# Use cases for generated URLs in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

Coming from a straight PHP and Drupal background, I am recently learning the Symfony2 framework. Currently I am in the routing chapter of the book. This is probably a simple question.

**What are some real world use cases for why one would want to generate URLs in a Symfony app?** I understand the code but I'm having a bit of trouble determining its practical applications.

I'm referring to [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls) should you need a refresher.

As always, thank you!

P.S. Symfony is amazing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to generate a URL whenever you need to link to anywhere in your application.

Let's say that you have an application that needs to manage some users. This means that you will probably have URLs like `/user/create`, `/user/edit/(user id)` and `/user/remove/(user id)`.

Whenever you display a link to edit a user you need to know on what URL you can find the page that allows you to edit a user. So you need to link to `/user/edit/(user id)`. One solution would be to have this as a fixed link so that in your code you could just write

```
<a href="/user/edit/<?= $currentUser->getId() ?>">edit this user</a>
```

But what if you want to change this URL scheme? Let's say someone is unhappy with the term "user", after all the humans managed by this system are not only users, they are actually "person"s! So now you need to change all the URLs containing "user". Probably there are quite a few places in your app where you have had to hardcode these URLs and now you will need to find and change all of them. Eugh.

But fear not, for Symfony routing comes to the rescue!

Instead of hardcoding these URLs, we can simply let the Symfony router generate them for us. This means that we first need to tell Symfony which routes we have, e.g. by adding the following YAML code to our routes config file:

```
user_edit:
  path:     /user/edit/{userId}
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:edit }
  requirements:
      userId:  \d+
```

This tells our application "Okay, whenever somebody requests a page that looks like `/user/edit/{userId}`, then you need to call the `editAction` method in our `UserController` class in the `AppBundle` namespace and you need to pass the `userId` as a parameter. Oh, and also you should only call the controller if `userId` is a valid integer with at least one number."

So this is how Symfony knows how to map URLs to controllers. But the goodness that comes along with it is that we can use this information for the reverse way as well.

Usually, in our application we do not really care about what the URL looks like for a certain action we want to perform. All we know is that when clicking a certain link, then the browser should jump to a page that allows me to edit a user. And since we just defined a route that takes us right there, we can have Symfony generate the correct URL to achieve just that.

So in your view you can now discard the hardcoded URL from earlier and instead replace it with a route generated by the Symfony router:

```
<a href="<?= $view['router']->generate('user_edit', ["userId" => $currentUser->getId()]) ?>">edit this user</a>
```

Now whenever you need to change what the URL actually looks like all you need to do is edit your routing config and not a lot of separate views.

Answer (score 2):

Because, imagine you want to change a given page URL and you've hardcoded it in 10 Twig templates. You will have to modify all these files. On the opposite, when using the routing component:

- You would only have to change the URL where the route is defined.
- The routing component "takes" care of the current environment you are using (dev, prod...)

Also note that is a bad practice to "switch environment", a typical issue is to hardcode an URL in a Javascript. In this case you can expose your Symfony2 routes in the Javascript by using a bundle like [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Comment: I posted the answer to my own question simultaneously but an up vote for you my friend. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I almost immediately realized their use and now I feel silly. :) For those who stop by this question in the future:

Notes about Generating URLs:

- Similar to the Drupal `l()` function, sometimes you need to generate links inside your application based on a variety of parameters.
- You don't always want to hardcode your links in case you decide to change paths sometime down the line.

In summary: Think of this as an alternative to using straight anchor tags with `href` elements all over the app and, instead, keeping things dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

## Use case

In the project I'm working I use `generateUrl` to redirect the user
after creating, editing an entity.

For example after creating a Service entity, I redirect the user to the view
of the just created Service.

### Controller

`return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myentity_view', array('id'=> $id)));`

### Additional note

In twig files, you can use the `path` function which call the routing component and generate url with given route name and parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the additional note! I really can be dense in the morning. I almost immediately realized what they would be for after my 2nd cup of coffee. Ha!